# How to handle method naming conflicts in viewmodels when using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

brand new to knockout and was wondering whether anyone could answer a question for me.

Is there a way to handle viewmodels with properties that are named the same when binding to elements on a page.  e.g

```
<input data-bind="value: prop1" />

function vm1(){
  this.prop1 = something
}

function vm2(){
  this.prop1 = something
}

ko.applybindings(new vm1());
ko.applybindings(new vm2());
```

ive tested this scenero on a textbox and basically the last binding wins. how can this scenerio get handled.

Comment: So what do you think which vm should win if you have only one input?

Comment: @nemesv evenn if there was 2 inputs the last binding would win

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this.

- specify the target of your binding, like this: `ko.applyBindings(new vm1(), document.getElementById("vm1"));`
- create a "master" viewmodel that holds your `vm1` and `vm2` models and [specify the binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Answer (score 1):

There you are binding to the page, so the last one wins, but you instead can bind a element or section of a page by passing the element in as the second argument.

```
<div id="one">
  <input data-bind="value: prop1" />
</div> 

<div id="two">
  <input data-bind="value: prop1" />
</div>

function vm1(){
  this.prop1 = something
}

function vm2(){
  this.prop1 = something
}

ko.applybindings(new vm1(), document.getElementById("one"));
ko.applybindings(new vm2(), document.getElementById("two"));
```

Comment: thanks for that.  Seems simple enough.  Is there a way to declaratively bind to the 2 divs?  e.g <div data-bind="vm1"></div>

Comment: Not that I know of, but a project I worked on we did something similar ourselves, it was pretty simple if I recall correctly, Just added a data-bindto="key" and bound the view models to all elements with that attribute.